# Newtonsoft JSON Schema Ignore Validations For Deserialize

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jsonschema

I have following JSON & class,

{
    "Id": 123,
    "FirstName": "fName",
    "LastName": "lName"
}

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize above JSON to create an instance of student class.

```
var body = //above json as string;

Student model = null;

JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Student));

using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(body)))
{
    using (JSchemaValidatingReader validatingReader = new JSchemaValidatingReader(reader) { Schema = schema })
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        model = serializer.Deserialize(validatingReader, typeof(Student));
    }
}
```

This is throwing an exception for string length validation, is there any way to deserialize the JSON by ignoring all data annotation validations?

Comment: Why not just remove the StringLength(4) if you don't want it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deserialize your data using the below code. You are validating before serializing due to which it is throwing error.

```
 var body ="{\"Id\":123,\"FirstName\":\"fNamesdcsdc\",\"LastName\":\"lName\"}";
            using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(body)))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                var model = serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(Student));
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
            String json="{ \"Id\": 123, \"FirstName\": \"fName\", \"LastName\": \"lName\" }";

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer=new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Student student = serializer.Deserialize<Student>(json);
```