# Best way to serialize object to JSON in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new in ASP.NET. I have an object tree structure and I want to use [Bootstrap-treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview). The problem is that it get json data as input.

What is the best way to convert my List to JSON?
Is it better to that in COntroller or better do it in View(JavaScript?)?
Mybe there is better ways to build a tree?

Comment: Since you are using asp.net-mvc, why don't just use `JsonResult` in `System.Web.Mvc`. Example: `Json(new{data = object});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer ..

[JsonConvertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660684/newtonsoft-json-schema-ignore-validations-for-deserialize/39661213#39661213)

```
 String json = "{ \"Id\": 123, \"FirstName\": \"fName\", \"LastName\": \"lName\" }";

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Student student = serializer.Deserialize<Student>(json);

            List<Student> students=new List<Student>();
            students.Add(student);


            String serializedStudentList = serializer.Serialize(students);
            var d = serializedStudentList;
            List<Student> serializedstudents = serializer.Deserialize<List<Student>>(serializedStudentList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you got object like this in list format-

```
Student: {
    Name:'SomeName',
    Address:'Address',
    Phone:'Phone'
},
.
.
.
```

Then you create a concrete class with properties as for one of repetitive object -

```
public class Student{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Address{get;set;}
    public string Phone{get;set;}
}
```

e.g. Object that you get -

```
var listObject= new List<Object> 
            {
                new {Name = "Alan", Address = "Doe", Phone = "123456"},
                new {Name = "Alan", Address = "Doe", Phone = "123456"},
            };
```

Serializing ^ object in Student Form -

using Newtonsoft.Json;

```
var studentSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<List<Student>>(listObject);
```

It will match propert names and will return you `List<Student>`. Now for treeview you try the same with `List` type property.